# Android Studio CMake/Ninja Not Used for Building an NDK project

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk, ninja

I have the following CMAKE & Ninja installed through Android Studio's SDK Tools:

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/bin/ninja --version
1.8.2
```

I run into "Error Configuring" while trying to build my project. Here is the build output:

```
Executable : /Users/ssk/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/bin/cmake
arguments : 
-H/Users/ssk/MyProject
-B/Users/ssk/MyProject/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a
-DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a
-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-16
-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/Users/ssk/MyProject/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
-DANDROID_NDK=/Users/ssk/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android
-DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=armeabi-v7a
-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=16
-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
-DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=/Users/ssk/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/Users/ssk/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake
-G Ninja
-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_statics
-DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=rtti exception
-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc
-DANDROID_NDK=/Users/ssk/android-ndk-r17c/
jvmArgs :
```

It's missing:

```
-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/Users/ssk/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/bin/ninja
```

**Error:**

```
 CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool
```

Only if I switch to CMake version say 3.6.3155560 it works. Otherwise, I have to install ninja from brew or macports.

Here is the snippet from my build.gradle:

```
 externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            // Linker flags and Visibility options keeps the size of the library small
            cppFlags "-std=c++11"
            arguments "-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static",
                      "-DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=rtti exceptions",
                      "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc"
        }
    }
```

How to fix it?

Comment: I was able to resolve this error message as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54666491/ndk-build-error-for-ninja-cmake-make-program-is-not-set/55676618

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install/Update CMake From Android Studio SDK Manager

[image: Install/Update CMake From Android Studio SDK Manager]

Check your CMake from sdk root directory if ninja exists. 
[image]

---

Below is not good.

```
cmake {
    cppFlags "-std=c++11"
    arguments "-DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a",
                "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-16",
                "-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static",
                "-DANDROID_CPP_FEATURES=rtti exceptions",
                "-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=libs"
}
```

Because, `ANDROID_PLATFORM` should be automatically decided by Android external native build system according to `minSdkVersion`, see below official document from [how `ANDROID_PLATFORM` works](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake#options):

> Instead of changing this flag directly, you should set the `minSdkVersion` property in the `defaultConfig` or `productFlavors` blocks of your module-level `build.gradle` file. This makes sure your library is used only by apps installed on devices running an adequate version of Android. The CMake toolchain then chooses the best platform version for the ABI you're building using the following logic:
>
> 1. If there exists a platform version for the ABI equal to `minSdkVersion`, CMake uses that version.
>      Otherwise,
> 2. if there exists platform versions lower than `minSdkVersion` for the ABI, CMake uses the highest of those platform versions. This is a reasonable choice because a missing platform version typically means that there were no changes to the native platform APIs since the previous available version.
> 3. Otherwise, CMake uses the next available platform version higher than `minSdkVersion`.

And, `-DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a` is not good as well. You should not define this parameter here. CMake will iterate **all your ABIs** according to your abiFilters automatically. If you just want to build `armeabi-v7a`, you can specify this using `abiFilter`, e.g.

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
    }
}
```

Also, `rtti` and `exceptions` are `cppFlags`, below should be the proper way to set these two flags.

```
cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions"
```

Ensure that your have properly configured `ANDROID_NDK` path, because according to your question, you have **TWO** version of NDK set, one is `-DANDROID_NDK=/Users/ssk/android-ndk-r17c/`, the other one is `-DANDROID_NDK=/Users/ssk/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle`. Config NDK path from `local.properties`:

```
ndk.dir=/Users/ssk/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=/Users/ssk/Library/Android/sdk
```

> what is the fix for -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja?

Add below `arguments` to the `cmake` config:

```
externalNativeBuild { 
    cmake { 
        ...
        version "3.10.2"
        arguments "-GAndroid Gradle - Ninja"
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does exist and it’s @1.8.2

Comment: Should be `-GAndroid Gradle - Ninja` rather than `-G Ninja`? How is your `gradle.build` like? See [Build arguments](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake#options)

Comment: Good catch, updated the question with the build.gradle. What is the fix? Thanks.

Comment: what is the fix for -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja? I am using gradle plugin 4.4. According to the documentation:

-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM <program-name> Tool to launch the native build system. The Gradle plugin sets this value to the CMake ninja generator bundled with the Android SDK.

Comment: Please update your `build.gradle` according to my comments and recompile to see the latest errors if any.

Comment: Updated to:

externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions"
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static",
                          "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc"
            }
        }

and I still see the problem.

Comment: remove `"-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc" ` You have TWO ndk paths, `-DANDROID_NDK=/Users/ssk/android-ndk-r17c/` and the `ndk-bundle` one, clean this also.Latest Android is using `clang`, not `gcc` any more.

Comment: @shizhen I have ninja in the cmake folder and I can run `ninja --version` in terminal. But still get: `CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.`;;;; There is no `ndk.dir` in `local.properties` as AS uses ndk-bundle.