# ndk build error for Ninja CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

I download ndk cmake and LLDB for ndk development.And then I create an project with 
c++ code，the application compiled error.

```
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.

...

Configuration failed.
External native generate JSON debug: JSON generation completed with problem
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

\* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateJsonModelDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error configuring
```

Comment: You downloaded CMake with the SDK Manager right? Not from some other place. I have three cmake versions in my Android SDK directory, and all of them contain `ninja.exe` in their `bin` subdirectory.

Comment: I downloaded CMake by Android studio.There is ninja in the directory /Users/fish/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/bin

Comment: Check similar issue discussed here [Android Studio CMake/Ninja Not Used for Building an NDK project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54473346/8034839)

Answer (score 8):

I resolved the issue with Valentin Safonnikov's comment:

> "Instead changing global path, you can add the path to cmake into local.properties file in the same dir as gradlew. `cmake.dir=D\:\\Android\\sdk\\cmake\\3.10.2.4988404`"

Edit: I only thought it was solved. All issues were only finally solved when I uninstalled cmake 3.10 and left only cmake 3.6 installed (it kept using 3.10 even with `cmake.dir=...\\3.6...`. I could see this in the textual gradle output:

```
External native generate JSON debug: executing cmake Executable : C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\cmake.exe
arguments : 
...
-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\ninja.exe
...
```

Comment: cmake.dir not helpful for me, "uninstalled cmake 3.10 " save me.

Comment: Removing folder "..../Sdk/platform-tools/cmake/3.10.2.4988404" helped me.

Answer (score 3):

I have solve the problem by add ninja to Path.

```
/Users/fish/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/bin
```

Comment: Instead changing global path, you can add the path to cmake into **local.properties** file in the same dir as gradlew.
`cmake.dir=D\:\\Android\\sdk\\cmake\\3.10.2.4988404`

Comment: @chefish What does it mean "add ninja to Path" ? Where can I find this 'Path'? Thanks