# Error while executing process "cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe" with arguments

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting below error, When I try to clean my Android NDK project

> 12:41:28: Executing task 'clean'...
>
> Executing tasks: [clean]
>
> Task :app:externalNativeBuildCleanDebug FAILED
>   Clean NextGenJNIWrapperExample armeabi-v7a
>   ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildCleanDebug'.
>     Build command failed.
>     Error while executing process D:\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.6.4111459\bin\cmake.exe with arguments {--build D:\ssl\NGC\NextGenConsole\app.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a --target clean}
>
>   ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': The system cannot find the file specified.
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
>   Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
>   See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD FAILED in 0s
>   1 actionable task: 1 executed
>   12:41:29: Task execution finished 'clean'.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/54473346/8034839 if it helps

Comment: is this 3.3.1? if not, try with 3.3.1, not 3.3.0.  relink the C++ project with "Build" > "Refresh linked C++ Project". Also check for  ...\.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a\cmake_build_command.txt, cmake_build_output.txt. also android_gradle_build.json.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue and i fixed it

```
 externalNativeBuild {
       cmake {
           path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
           version "3.10.2"  // just add current installed version of CMake
    
       }
    }
```