# Pass build type ("debug"/"release") to ndk-build

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, ndk-build

Android Studio, a project with an NDK library, using ndkBuild with Android.mk. My build uses a static library dependency, and the static library exists as a debug and as a release flavor, in separate directories. The makefile goes:

```
#Ref to libfoo
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := foo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FOOPROJECT)\foo\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\obj\local\$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)\libfoo.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

`LOCAL_SRC_FILES` has the `debug` flavor hard-coded as a part of the path. Not good. I'd like to use either "debug" or "release" there, depending on the current build type.

Is the current build type available in the makefile as a variable? If not, is is possible to pass it to ndk-build via the gradle file?

Comment: Just FYI, this is [how you can manage the different paths with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53409479/android-ndk-path-variable-for-strip-command-in-cmake-build-tool-chain), but not ndk-build.

Comment: Do you still want to build the rest of your native code in release mode? Otherwise there's the `APP_OPTIM` variable.

Comment: No, I want to keep the debug/release distinction both in this project and in the dependencies and make them match. Good find, let me play with that.

Comment: Bingo. Make an answer, I'll accept. For the record, `APP_OPTIM` is set to "debug" even if "JNI debuggable" is set to false on the debug type, I've checked.

Comment: "JNI debuggable" means your JNI code can be debugged, it does not mean anything to the "build type".

Comment: My point was, one might reasonably expect `APP_OPTIM` to reflect the compiler flags being used as opposed to the specified build type. Meanwhile, if "JNI debuggable" is off, one might similarly expect the compiler flags to be identical to those of the release build.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Michael's `APP_OPTIM` is better. Once he writes it up, I'll accept. For now, I'll leave this here.

---

Couldn't find a built-in variable, did a Gradle trick:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                arguments "BUILD_TYPE=release"
            }}
    }
    debug {
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                arguments "BUILD_TYPE=debug"
            }}
    }
}
```

Then the line in Android.mk becomes:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FOOPROJECT)\foo\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\$(BUILD_TYPE)\obj\local\$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)\libfoo.a
```

Answer (score 1):

`NDK_DEBUG` is the var what you need, `1` is debug, `0` is release.

```
ifeq ($(NDK_DEBUG), 1)
    BUILD_TYPE := debug
else
    BUILD_TYPE := release
endif
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := foo
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FOOPROJECT)\foo\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\$(BUILD_TYPE)\obj\local\$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)\libfoo.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Other useful vars:

- `APP_BUILD_SCRIPT`: `Android.mk` path
- `NDK_APPLICATION_MK`: `Application.mk` path
- `APP_ABI`: Same like `TARGET_ARCH_ABI`
- `NDK_OUT`: the build obj path
- `NDK_LIBS_OUT`: build lib path
- `APP_PLATFORM`: Target os and api version,like `android-21`

You can check this file :
`ProjectPath/ModuleName/build/.cxx/$(BUILD_TYPE)/xxxx/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/android_gradle_build_command_ModuleName_$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI).txt`
too see more info.

And here is a [Android NDK demo](https://github.com/peerless2012/NDKDemo), you can check the `lib_module_provider` and `lib_module_beneficiary` to see how to use `pre-built` library by `ndk-build` or `cmake`